# JavaScript: Declaring VAR with 'or' statement

Tags: javascript, if-statement

the code is something like this

```
var $page_products = $page_name == 'products-uninterruptible-power-supply.php' OR 'products-uninterruptible-power-supply-np2031.php';
```

i already tried using

```
var $page_products = $page_name == 'products-uninterruptible-power-supply.php' || 'products-uninterruptible-power-supply-np2031.php';
```

but it is still not working. thanks in advance!

Comment: What are you trying to do? What type is `var $page_products` supposed to be?

Comment: Please explain what you are trying to achieve - I assumed one thing with my answer, but Josh assumed something else. (By the way, this had nothing to do with jQuery, so I've retagged it as 'javascript' and changed the title to match).

Comment: @nnnnnn I'm curious as well and honestly feel a bit narrow minded for not thinking of the other possible desire.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your intention is to declare one variable, `$page_products`, which will be set to true if the `$page_name` is equal to either of those two strings and false otherwise, do this:

```
var $page_products = $page_name == 'products-uninterruptible-power-supply.php'
           || $page_name == 'products-uninterruptible-power-supply-np2031.php';
```

EDIT: I just noticed that both page names start with the same four words, so instead of comparing to each string it may suit you to test whether the value in `$page_name` starts with those words, e.g.,:

```
var $page_products =
           $page_name.indexOf('products-uninterruptible-power-supply') === 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work

```
var $page_products = ($page_name == 'products-uninterruptible-power-supply.php' || $page_name == 'products-uninterruptible-power-supply-np2031.php');
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to assign the file name conditionally, then you'll want the ternary operator:

```
var $page_products = ($page_name == 'products-uninterruptible-power-supply.php') ?
    'products-uninterruptible-power-supply.php' : 
    'products-uninterruptible-power-supply-np2031.php';
```